# add new column comparing dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, iteration

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id    status    date_1         date_2
1       yes     2018-12-18     NaT
2       no      2018-06-30     2016-05-31
3       no      NaT            2014-04-15
4       yes     2010-01-01     2018-05-10
```

All of the dates are in pandas datetime format. I would like to create a new column in this dataframe that compares the date_1 and date_2 column to pick the earliest date and put it in the new column, or if either date_1 or date_2 has `NaT` then to put the other value in the new column like so:

```
id    status    date_1         date_2        new_column
1       yes     2018-12-18     NaT           2018-12-18
2       no      2018-06-30     2016-05-31    2016-05-31
3       no      NaT            2014-04-15    2014-04-15
4       yes     2010-01-01     2018-05-10    2010-01-01
```

I thought about an if statement with iterrows() to do this, but not sure how to put value of a row in the new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just take the minimum via [`pd.DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html), since `skipna=True` by default:

```
df['new_col'] = df[['date_1', 'date_2']].min(1)

print(df)

   id status     date_1     date_2    new_col
0   1    yes 2018-12-18        NaT 2018-12-18
1   2     no 2018-06-30 2016-05-31 2016-05-31
2   3     no        NaT 2014-04-15 2014-04-15
3   4    yes 2010-01-01 2018-05-10 2010-01-01
```